# Знаки препинания.

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Я считаю себя правым,как мне это доказать?

1.Никак()это закон,ты можешь лишь только смириться с ним.

2.Никак()это Виктор,ты можешь лишь только смириться с ним.

Какие знаки ставятся в этих случаях?Разные ли они?Могут ли тут быть различные вариации в зависимости от смысла?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак. Это закон,ты можешь лишь только смириться с ним.
Никак:это закон,ты можешь лишь только смириться с ним.
Во втором предложении - такие же варианты.

Comment: Давайте все-таки школьники будут делать свои задания самостоятельно!